# Implement tab-bar and slide menu together in ios

Tags: ios, slider, tabbar

I am new to ios and working on project in which i need to implement tab-bar and slide menu together in same application and i need tab bar in all view either i navigate from menu also,  can't find any solution or any demo for these please help me out